# cocos2d-x/firebase/admob failed loading interstitial ad

Tags: java, android, firebase, admob, cocos2d-x

I am following this official guide to integrate firebase/admob into my cocos2d-x project.

https://firebase.google.com/docs/admob/cpp/quick-start

This is my code:

```
void Helper::initializeAdmob() {

    // Initialize Firebase for Android.
    firebase::App* app = firebase::App::Create(firebase::AppOptions(), JniHelper::getEnv(), JniHelper::getActivity());
    // Initialize AdMob.
    firebase::admob::Initialize(*app, admob_app_id);
    firebase::admob::Initialize(*app);

    interstitial_ad = new firebase::admob::InterstitialAd();
    interstitial_ad->Initialize(static_cast<firebase::admob::AdParent>(getAdParent()), testing_boolean ? interstitial_id_for_testing : interstitial_id);

}

void Helper::requestInterstitialAd() {

    if (interstitial_ad->InitializeLastResult().status() == firebase::kFutureStatusComplete && interstitial_ad->InitializeLastResult().error() == firebase::admob::kAdMobErrorNone) {
        firebase::admob::AdRequest request = {};
        const char* myKindleFireDeviceId = "7E9D27D370EA69CD2B962EE957B1C198";
        static const char* testDevices[] = {myKindleFireDeviceId};
        request.test_device_ids = testDevices;
        request.test_device_id_count = sizeof(testDevices) / sizeof(testDevices[0]);
        interstitial_ad->LoadAd(request);
    }

}

void Helper::showInterstitialAd() {
    if (interstitial_ad->LoadAdLastResult().status() == firebase::kFutureStatusComplete && interstitial_ad->LoadAdLastResult().error() == firebase::admob::kAdMobErrorNone) {
        interstitial_ad->Show();
    }
}
```

The `initializeAdmob()` was executed fine. 
Then for `requestInterstitialAd()`, I got 400 error:

```
12-23 22:57:28.743 24354-25845/com.xx.xx W/Ads: Received error HTTP response code: 400
12-23 22:57:28.756 24354-25845/com.xx.xx W/Ads: There was a problem getting an ad response. ErrorCode: 0
12-23 22:57:28.759 24354-24354/com.xx.xx W/Ads: Failed to load ad: 0
```

Edit:

I am using kindle fire.

Edit 2:

My kindle fire was connected to internet.

Edit 3:

I was using my own admob app id, and the test id for android interstitial ad

Edit 4:

I tried banner ad and get the same result. 
I also tried simulator and same result.